# Разные ориентации листов в одной внешней печатной форме отчета - такое возможно?

Tags: 1с, печать

**Добрый день!**

Имеем внеш. печатную форму на 3 страницы (шапка 1 старницы, 1 - таблица данных, 3 - подвал, подписи всякие).

Требуется, чтобы **1ый лист был Портретный, 2ой -  Альбомный (т.к. таблица широкая очень), 3ий - Портретный**.
Переход между страницами осуществляется с помощью горизонтальных разделителей.

Реально ли такую задачу реализовать стандартными средствами?

1C:8.2

Comment: В названии ошибся - не отчет а внешняя печ.форма.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод в лоб:
Поскольку страницы у вас разделены разделителями, то можно поступить так; создать массив табличных документов, где элемент массива - страница.

```
МассивТабличныхДокументов[i].ОриентацияСтраницы = ОриентацияСтраницы.Ландшафт;
МассивТабличныхДокументов[i+1].ОриентацияСтраницы = ОриентацияСтраницы.Портрет;
```

**UPD:**

Тогда вы их показываете в один табличный документ (например ТабличныйДокумент формы), а храните на клиенте как массив. Создаете кнопку Печать которая будет иметь обработчик:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура Печать(Команда)
    Для каждого текТабДок Из МассивТабличныхДокументов Цикл
        текТабДок.Напечатать();
    КонецЦикла;
КонецПроцедуры
```

Синтаксис метода Напечатать

> Синтаксис:
>
> Напечатать(<ДиалогПечати>)  Параметры:
>
> <ДиалогПечати> (необязательный)
>
> Тип: РежимИспользованияДиалогаПечати.
> Определяет необходимость показа
> диалога печати перед печатью. Значение
> по умолчанию: НеИспользовать 
> Описание:
>
> Выводит табличный документ на печать.
>
> Доступность:
>
> Тонкий клиент, веб-клиент, толстый
> клиент.  Пример:
>
> ТабДок.Напечатать();

Comment: а как потом вывести эти таб.доки?
Предполагается, что они должны выводиться пользователю в один табличный документ.